# Activiti: Email Character Encoding Issue

Tags: java, workflow, activiti, bpmn, workflow-activity

I have a bpmn project with Activiti. When Activiti engine sends a mail,  characters are distorted (ex: İİİııı => ?????? )

I tried this bpmn xml configration

```
    <activiti:field name="charset">
      <activiti:string><![CDATA[UTF-8]]></activiti:string>
    </activiti:field>
```

When I display the raw content of the mail:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

How do I configure encoding mail content?